# rest web service in php

Tags: php, rest

Can anyone please tell me how to write the method in REST web service,
Requirements: 
User input will be given in the text box.
Now we have to call the web service and echo back the same text to the user without refreshing the page.
Please can anyone answer as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Radu how could you possibly quote something this loosely scoped.

Comment: @Radu you surely don't believe that is his only requirement? Remember what a client think they need is normally not even close to what they actually need. And I agree that this is not a real question.

Comment: @Radu Ha. Sarcastic on the internet, fools me every time. You sir win this bout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PHP REST micro framework: http://peej.github.com/tonic/